# Identical zeroes of two different nth degree polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

f(x) and g(x) are two $n^{th}$ degree polynomial equations of x.
$f(x)= f_0+f_1*x^1+f_2*x^2+...+ f_n*x^n$

$g(x)= g_0+g_1*x^1+g_2*x^2+...+ g_n*x^n$

If one is to say that zeroes of both the equations are identical then can the following be said:

$\frac{f_0}{g_0}=\frac{f_1}{g_1}=\frac{f_2}{g_2}=...=\frac{f_n}{g_n}=constant$

Comment: No, take $f=(X-1)^2(X+1)=X^3-X^2-X+1$ and $g=(X-1)(X+1)^2=X^3+X^2-X-1$.

Comment: Yes, if the zeros are simple.

Comment: Simple zero means the solution or roots don't repeat themselves as answers? For eg the equations presented by @Tuvasbien?

Comment: It means that the zeros of $f$ are not zeros of $f'$. In my example $-1$ is a simple zero of $f$ but not $1$.

Comment: Ohh... I think I understood the concept of simple zeroes. Is there any way to find out if an equation has all zeroes simple zeroes or not? Or do you have to factorize it ...

Comment: If you have a zero $\alpha$ of $f$, compute $f'$ and if $f'(\alpha)\neq 0$, it means that the zero $\alpha$ is simple.

Comment: Compute $\gcd(f,f')$.